# CSS styling precedence

Tags: html, css

I have two CSS classes:

```
.thick-green-border {
border-color: green;
border-width: 10px;
border-style: solid;
border-radius:10px;
}

.smaller-image {
width: 100px;
border-radius:30px;
}
```

Usage in HTML document:

```
<img class="thick-green-border smaller-image" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/relaxing-cat.jpg" alt="A cute orange cat lying on its back.">
```

When the image element is assigned both the classes, the rule for the style **border-radius** described in the class `.smaller-image` is taking effect, not the radius set inside `thick-green-border` class. That is the border-radius of the image is becoming 30px, not 10px.

Can anyone please tell me why? I have tried changing the order in which the classes are assigned to the image but the result is the same.

Answer (score 0):

Change the order of the classes in the CSS.

```css
.thick-green-border {
  border-color: green;
  border-width: 10px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
.smaller-image {
  width: 100px;
  border-radius: 30px;
}
.smaller-image2 {
  width: 100px;
  border-radius: 30px;
}
.thick-green-border2 {
  border-color: green;
  border-width: 10px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<img class="thick-green-border smaller-image" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/relaxing-cat.jpg" alt="A cute orange cat lying on its back.">

<img class="thick-green-border2 smaller-image2" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/relaxing-cat.jpg" alt="A cute orange cat lying on its back.">
```

They both have the same hierarchy level, so the latter one will be applied.

Comment: Alright! Both the classes being on the same level was the issue then! Thanks @Jamie-barker

Answer (score -1):

Is this what you want?

```css
.thick-green-border {
border-color: green;
border-width: 10px;
border-style: solid;
border-radius:10px;
display: inline-block;
}

.smaller-image {
width: 100px;
border-radius:30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="thick-green-border">
<img class="smaller-image" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/relaxing-cat.jpg" alt="A cute orange cat lying on its back.">
  </div>
```

Comment: OP wants to override the border radius set by `.thick-green-border`, not to have both borders.

Comment: fine, I misunderstood what he ment

Comment: I want the border set by "thick-green-border" class. @cHao got this right.

Comment: so why don't you just remove the border style in .smaller-image?

Comment: I understand your point. And I could very well do that. But I just wanted to know why the border style in the 2nd class was in effect and not the first one. I totally forgot they were on the same level @GabrielChiHongLee